# Unknown white borders showing on use of Nicinabox's Superslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm using Nicinabox's SuperSlider jquery plugin for a photography site that i'm building currently. It all works perfect, except for one minor bug. On the page load, there is a border showing at the bottom and right hand side of the page.

[image]

Upon attempting to resize the window, it automatically clips to the correct size and the bordered area dissapears. I've been going through the code and i can't seem to figure it out.

Link to the site itself is http://www.acoustica.me. Maybe i'm doing something wrong, or code i have is interfering. Regardless, i thought i'd ask here on the off chance someone might know.

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding this to the style sheet and let me know if it makes a change, `img { border: 0!important; margin: 0!important; padding: 0!important; }`.

Comment: Nope. Definately not. I'm thinking it might be to do with the slider itself. The spacing on it is the perfect spacing you would need to show the scrollbar on the right or on the bottom. Seems really strange.

Comment: It is very strange and I can't really see anything that is causing this. The abundance of inline styles is not a plus but I wouldn't expect it to be the culprit.

Comment: I found the answer. My HTML element didn't have an overflow, so it was still wrapping. Thank you regardless. I know it's pretty messy code, but the cleanup will come later. Haha. I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem, at least you got it solved and can now figure out how to clean it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that i was wrong. The slider wasn't the issue, my css was. There was no overflow set on the  element; my highest element on my page.

```
html{

overflow: hidden;

}
```

Problem solved. Sorry for the hassle.